# getting data from server and passing it around pages Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, geofire

I have a service that fetches data from an api endpoint in my ionic app. Here is the function that gets data from the server.

```
getDriverInfo(username)
{
return this.http.get(this.base_url + 'user/' + username, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.access_token)
});
}
```

i have a page that gets the data is responds with.

```
 handleResponse(data) {

  this.db.getDriverInfo(data.username).subscribe(
          resp => {
              this.driverData = resp;
              this.driverId = this.driverData.driver.id;
              this.driverUserid = this.driverData.id;
              console.log(this.driverData);
          }
  );
  this.token.handle(data.access_token);
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage, {
        driverData: this.driverData,
        driverId: this.driverId,
        driverUserId: this.driverUserId
  });
}

toDash()
{
let loading = this.loadCtrl.create({
  content:'Logging In...'
});

loading.present();

this.auth.login(this.form).subscribe(
 data => { 
   this.handleResponse(data);
    loading.dismiss();
 },
 error => { 
   this.handleError(error);
 loading.dismiss();
 }
);

}
```

console.log() this.driverData gives me the data.

in my homePage i try to save the data in variables like so

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform,
          public geo: Geolocation, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
          public driverProvider: DriverProvider, public alertCtrl: AlertController,
          public navParams: NavParams, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public db: DbProvider
          ) {
            this.driverDetails = this.navParams.get('driver_data');
            this.driverUserId = this.navParams.get('driver_user_id');
            this.driverDBId = this.navParams.get('driver_id');
            this.isOnline = this.navParams.get('isOnline');
            console.log(this.driverDetails);
          }
```

but console.log gives me undefined. How can i pass the data around efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `HomePage` change the following:

```
this.driverDetails = this.navParams.get('driver_data');
```

into this:

```
 this.driverDetails = this.navParams.get('driverData');
```

When you are sending the data to the second page, you are using the attribute `driverData`, thus to recieve this attribute you need to add it exactly the same in the `get()`

To get all the data, you can do the following inside the constructor:

```
this.allData = this.navParams.data;
console.log(this.allData);
```

Check the docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) for more information.